# Can I change a variable in different functions by using a PHP switch?

Tags: php, function, variables, switch-statement

I'm trying to change a variable value when it is in a certain function. I think  the best to see the code:

```
function display_content(){
    switch (function) {
        case "recipe_list_dishes()":
            $dish_type = "'dishes'";
        break;
        case "recipe_list_desserts()":
            $dish_type = "'desserts'";
        break;
        case "recipe_list_snacks()":
            $dish_type = "'snacks'";
        break;
    }
}

function recipe_list_dishes() {
    display_content();
    echo $dish_type; // it should be 'dishes'
}
```

I know it might look silly to someone experienced, but I don't really know how to change the variable according to the function. Is that possible?

Comment: Return $dish_type from display_contents and assign it to a variable in recipe_list_dishes...

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the variable $dish_type and assign it to a new variable in the other function. Furthermore you'd need to pass the function name to be examined.

I've made a couple of changes to your code:

```
function display_content($function){
    $dish_type = 'unknown';
    switch ($function) {
        case "recipe_list_dishes()":
            $dish_type = "'dishes'";
        break;
        case "recipe_list_desserts()":
            $dish_type = "'desserts'";
        break;
        case "recipe_list_snacks()":
            $dish_type = "'snacks'";
        break;
    }
    return $dish_type;
}

function recipe_list_dishes() {
    // maybe __FUNCTION__ will work as well..
    $dish_type = display_content('recipe_list_dishes()');
    echo $dish_type; // it should be 'dishes'
}
```